# Social Network Graph Library for Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, graph

I am responsible for front-end of a social network analysis project and I am supposed to develop a web application representing graph of users and other features with drag-able and click-able nodes. As I am using *angularjs* for my web application, what is the best technology to represent desired graphs.
I searched for **d3.js** technology using in *angularjs* but I didn't find any useful example. I need an agile way to show some working example soon.

Comment: Voting to close, but if I was you I'd just create an angular directive that wraps `d3`?

Comment: You are wright, I've started to do this. But I wish it was a better way.

Comment: Why "Voting to close" ? @Mark

Comment: Off topic because ... Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow ...

Comment: OK, but where should I ask it? @Mark